# Is there any testing exchange available to test smart contact from rinkeby test network?

Tags: myetherwallet, testnets, rinkeby

I am working on a smart contract and thinking about future scope of the coin so I would like to ask.
Is there any testing exchange available to test smart contact from rinkeby test network?

Answer (score 0):

Kyber Token Exchange available for trading following this [documentation](https://github.com/KyberNetwork/smart-contracts/blob/master/integration.md). After following this documentation you may get stuck on sending values in

```
Function Trade(.....),
```

So you must use

```
Function SwapEtherToToken(.....). //Easy, just send ethers and get tokens.
```